# How to create a redis listener inside a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

My scenario is as follows:

I have a Rails app which has an active record model for writing down system events.  Those system events can come from the rails app or from a separate Ruby app.  The ruby app currently publishes its events to a Redis queue.

Is there a way within the Rails app to start a Redis listener and subscribe to the queue?

Comment: Rails is a web framework. Request-response cycle. No long-running stuff. You need s separate daemon that will process that queue and write data to a database. Your rails model will then fetch data from the DB as usual.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @sergio your rails application is not the place for a redis **client**. A rails web application is a **server** side application which responds to requests from clients. That is why, what you need is a separate process (preferably a daemon) which acts as a client to your redis server.

To daemonize your redis client you can use the `daemons` gem. I typically place my daemons in `<app-root>/lib/daemons/`

You can load your complete Rails environment in your daemon process by including these lines at the beginning :

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/application"
Rails.application.require_environment!
```

That way you will have access to your models and can interact with your DB through your model classes.